# Boost compile error "invalid template argument for independent_bits_engine" 1.79.0 with VS2022

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2022

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/miller_rabin.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::random::mt11213b base_gen(clock());
  std::independent_bits_engine<boost::random::mt11213b, 100, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int> gen(base_gen);

  boost::multiprecision::cpp_int g1 = gen();
  std::cout << "This is a 100 bits generator: " << g1 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Produces the following error while compiling:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2338   static_assert failed: 'invalid template argument for independent_bits_engine: N4659 29.6.1.1 [rand.req.genl]/1f requires one of unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long' ConsoleApplication1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\random 1490
```

What could be the issue? I have correctly updated the header and liner paths in the build configuration. I can see no red squiggly underscores under the words confirming that the paths are updated correctly. The above error is at compile time.

Comment: I don't see `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>` in the list of valid types provided by the error. I assume that is the argument it is complaining about.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `boost::random::independent_bits_engine`? https://godbolt.org/z/jnvj56E53

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja. I was also missing either ```
#include <boost/random/independent_bits.hpp>``` or ``` 
#include <boost/random.hpp>```